# Trimming MySQL string after a given string

Tags: mysql

I'm drawing a blank on this MySQL command. I have a set of strings like so in a variable named pagetitle in a table called scanner:

```
Marketing analytics via Christopher Penn
```

And I want to lop off everything after, including the via, to yield:

```
Marketing analytics
```

I did this:

```
UPDATE scanner SET pagetitle = SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ' via ' FROM pagetitle) FROM scanner
```

Which according to the manual should do what I'm looking for, but it's still yielding the original string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TRAILING` option with `TRIM` refers to trailing characters, not entire words begun with a certain word.  Try using `INSTR` here:

```
UPDATE scanner
SET pagetitle = LEFT(pagetitle, INSTR(pagetitle, 'via') - 2);
WHERE pagetitle REGEXP '[[:<:]]via[[:>:]]';
```

### Demo

If you are using MySQL 8+ or later, then we can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE scanner
SET pagetitle = REGEXP_REPLACE(pagetitle, '\\s+via.*', '');
```